Can Vue devtools cause high CPU usage if app/tab left open for long time?
I have a Vue app where on one page all it does is sets an interval on mounted to fetch something from an API every minute. Now if I leave it like this for a long time, CPU usage starts creeping, while the app is doing nothing. In the performance tab in chrome dev tools, I recorded a 2 seconds timespan, and I see a lot of stuff that originates from backend.js which if I click I see the source is vue-devtools related: handshake, sendListening, postMessage. My suspicion is that this is what's causing the high CPU usage as nothing else is really happening as seen in the performance tab. I noticed the same although in production from the same browser, where devtools inspection is disabled - but the devtools extension was still in by browser, hence my suspicion.
I will test it in other browser, with and without extensions (so like open the app and just leave it for a day), but I can't really think of anything else, since the app is literally not doing anything other than doing one request every minute. If I refresh the tab the symptom goes away. My first suspicion because of this was maybe some classic memory leak or such, but memory footprint is roughly the same after I refreshed - and again, the page does nothing computation heavy.

